# my flowaverage function wont produce an output

Tags: python

Part 3 – Create the Functions to Analyse a Packet
the flowaverage function wont produce an output please help - Python

.

For you to know if a packet is involved in malicious activity or not you must first identify characteristics of malicious traffic and then find a way to represent this in python. For this assignment we will use four metrics to determine if a packet is malicious or not.

Average Packet Size – This metric will accept a list of packets and gets the average payload size of all the packets. It will return a list of packets that are above the average of the list.

here is my code

````
` def makePacket(srcIP, dstIP, length, prt, sp, dp, sqn, pld):
  return ("PK", srcIP, dstIP, [length, prt, [sp, dp], sqn, pld])
    
 def getPacketSrc(pkt):
  return pkt[1]``
    
 def getPacketDst(pkt):
  return pkt[2]
    
 def getPacketDetails(pkt):
    return pkt[3]

    
 def isPacket(pkt):
    return type(pkt[1]) != type([]) and pkt[0] == "PK" and type(pkt) == type(())

 def isEmptyPkt(pkt):
    return getPacketDetails(pkt) == []

 def getLength(pkt):
    a = getPacketDetails(pkt)
    return a[0]

 def getProtocol(pkt):
    a = getPacketDetails(pkt)
    return a[1]

 def getSrcPort(pkt):
    a = getPacketDetails(pkt)
    b = a[2]
    return b[0]

def getDstPort(pkt):
    a = getPacketDetails(pkt)
    b = a[2]
    return b[1]

 def getSqn(pkt):
    a = getPacketDetails(pkt)
    return a[3]

 def getPayloadSize(pkt):
    a= getPacketDetails(pkt)
    return a[4]

 def flowAverage(pkt):
    
    packets=[]
    payloads=[]
    for p in pkt:
        list(getPacketDetails(p)[1])
        payloads.append(pkt)[1]
        total=0
        for p in payloads:
            total=total+p
            avg=total/len(payloads)
            return avg
    


 def suspPort(pkt):
    if getSrcPort(pkt) > 500 or getDstPort(pkt)>500:
        return True
    else:
        return False

 def suspProto(pkt):
    protoLst=["HTTP","SMTP", "UDP", "TCP", "DHCP"]
    if getProtocol(pkt) not in protoLst:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def ipBlacklist(pkt):
    ipBlackList=[["213.217.236.184","444.221.232.94","149.88.83.47","223.70.250.146","169.51.6.136","229.22369.24"]]
    if getPacketSrc(pkt) in IpBlackList:
        return True
    else:
        return False
`
```


`



im expecting

Input 
111.202.230.44 62.82.29.190 3 HTTP 80 3463 1562431 87
Sample Output 0

Output

Average Packet Size => [('PK', '333.230.18.207', '213.217.236.184', [56, 'IRC', [501, 5643], 1762431, 318]), ('PK', '444.221.232.94', '50.168.160.19', [1003, 'TCP', [4657, 4875], 1962431, 428])]
Suspicious Port (pkt) => True
Suspicious Port (pk3) => True
Suspicious Protocol (pkt) => False
Suspicious Protocol (pk4) => False
IP Blacklist (pkt) => False
IP Blacklist (pk5) => False
````

Comment: It looks like you're returning after calculating the first packet. Should the `return` be after the for loop?

Comment: elaboarate more please

Comment: Is `flowAverage` supposed to be called with a list of packets? The argument name `pkt` doesn't make that clear.

Comment: yes its supposed to do that

Comment: so what argument do you suggest i use

Comment: I would call the argument `pkt_list` or something similar to distinguish it from functions like `getLength(pkt)` which take only a single packet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you are returning early from your for loop, instead of iterating over all the packets. To get the average of the packet lengths, you could do something like this:

```py
def flowAverage(pkt_list):
    payloads = []
    large_packets = []
    for pkt in pkt_list:
        payloads.append(getPayloadSize(pkt))
    total = sum(payloads)
    avg = total / len(payloads)
    
    for pkt in pkt_list:
        if getPayloadSize(pkt) > avg:
            large_packets.append(pkt)
    return large_packets
```

Comment: ok when i use this i get an output so first of all im grateful for that howver its not returning the output i need which is [('PK', '333.230.18.207', '213.217.236.184', [56, 'IRC', [501, 5643], 1762431, 318]), ('PK', '444.221.232.94',

Comment: i am getting 223.0 as output

Comment: The first part was for calculating the average packet size, I've added more so that it returns the list of packets that are larger than average.

Comment: ok great using this i get the following output Average Packet Size => [('PK', '444.221.232.94', '50.168.160.19', [1003, 'TCP', [4657, 4875], 1962431, 428])]

Comment: i need it like this [('PK', '333.230.18.207', '213.217.236.184', [56, 'IRC', [501, 5643], 1762431, 318]), ('PK', '444.221.232.94', '50.168.160.19', [1003, 'TCP', [4657, 4875], 1962431, 428])] any ideas i appreciate your patience by the way

Comment: If the average packet payload size if 207, it should only return the second packet, since the first has payload size of 57. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: i am checking if to see if i forgot to mention anything

Comment: OK I FIGURED IT OUT

Comment: i was supposed to put back the payload size in the argument and not the get length

Comment: I've updated my answer to use the correct function, too.